Why seemingly wrong proof works in proving $\varphi^{n+1} = \varphi \cdot F_{n+1} + F_n$ by induction?
I was reading this post on this site. Which says:

Fibonacci Rules:
\begin{align*}
  F_0 = 0 && F_1 = 1 && F_{n+2} = F_n + F_{n+1}
\end{align*}
Prove, by induction, that $\varphi^{n+1} = \varphi \cdot F_{n+1} + F_n$ for all natural numbers $n$.

And the accepted answer is,

If $\varphi^{k+1}=\varphi F_{k+1}+F_{k}$ then:
$$\begin{align*}
\varphi^{k+2}&=\varphi\varphi^{k+1}=\varphi^2F_{k+1}+\varphi F_{k}\\
&=(\varphi+1)F_{k+1}+\varphi F_k=\varphi(F_{k+1}+F_k)+F_{k+1}\\
&=\varphi F_{k+2}+F_{k+1}
\end{align*}$$

But when I was trying to solving this problem on my own, this approach came to my mind,
If $\varphi^{k+1}=\varphi F_{k+1}+F_{k}$ then:
$$\varphi^{k+2}=\varphi \times (\varphi F_{k+1})+ \varphi F_k$$
Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}=\varphi$, replacing $\phi= \dfrac{F_{k+2}}{F_{k+1}}$ and $\phi= \dfrac{F_{k+1}}{F_{k}}$ in the above expression leads to,
$$\varphi^{k+2}=\varphi F_{k+2}+F_{k+1}$$
But then I realized that we can replace the $\varphi$ by the ratio of Fibonacci's numbers only if the index tend to infinity for example it is wrong to say $\frac{21}{13}=\frac{34}{21}=\varphi$. As I believe in the induction proof we don't assume $k\to\infty$, I'm wondering how this wrong steps lead to correct result?!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion From something false (like $\phi= \dfrac{F_{k+2}}{F_{k+1}}$ and $\phi= \dfrac{F_{k+1}}{F_{k}}$), you can derive anything you like. And, "we can replace the $\varphi$ by the ratio of Fibonacci's numbers only if the index tend to infinity" makes no sense. Neither does "in the induction proof we don't assume $k\to\infty$".

First, why can you replace for each $k$ the ratio by its limit? Also, how do you prove that the limit is $\varphi$ without your inductive claim?

Does this answer your question? Does False logically entails everything

Is $\phi=\varphi$?

@JoséCarlosSantos Yes I used the same notation as the referenced post.

I take it you haven't had much experience with grading math homework/exams. When and if you do, you will discover that stumbling into the correct answer by massively incorrect reasoning is far more common than you would believe. This is an example of the law of small numbers: when the number of outcomes is limited, disparate processes often lead to the same conclusion by coincidence.
